# Magento 2 extension failed after submit

Tags: magento2.3, extensions, magento2marketplace

We have submitted the Magento 2 extension today, and it's failed the reason below result.

Earlier we Magento shown list of possible errors to rectify, Now can't find the same.
The result file as shown below.

[image]

```
 "commands": [
      {
        "command": "composerConfigRepository0",
        "output": "Finished with the \"0\" exit code."
      },
      {
        "command": "composerConfigKeys0",
        "output": "Finished with the \"0\" exit code."
      },
      {
        "command": "echo \"127.0.0.1 magento2.docker\" >> /etc/hosts",
        "output": "Finished with the \"0\" exit code. Process output: \"\"."
      },
      {
        "command": "cp /usr/share/eqp/VarnishMftfTool/etc/varnish-config/magento-fixtures-profile.xml /usr/share/eqp-varnish-mftf/magento/magento-fixtures-profile.xml",
        "output": "Finished with the \"0\" exit code. Process output: \"\"."
      },
      {
        "command": "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down --volumes",
        "output": "Finished with the \"0\" exit code. Process output: \"\"."
      },
      {
        "command": "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --detach --no-color",
        "output": "Finished with the \"0\" exit code. Process output: \"10.2: Pulling from library/mariadb\nDigest: sha256:187b02ad495b0cc95662f3382bf8a811319b54d224bd12d24919988137de7cb9\nStatus: Downloaded newer image
        for 126150169089.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/library/mariadb:10.2\n5.0: Pulling from library/redis\nDigest: sha256:12664f201c777d41247ec863bf92cb8145381c0de4fcabfb58f3c61f6ff2dd3e\nStatus: 
        .......................
        ....
                    Pulling from mailhog/mailhog\nDigest: sha256:8d76a3d4ffa32a3661311944007a415332c4bb855657f4f6c57996405c009bea\nStatus: Downloaded newer image for 126150169089.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mailhog/mailhog:latest\n\"."
      },
      {
        "command": "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run --rm build composer require --no-ansi abcsolutions/module-dynamics365:2.2.0",
        "output": "Finished with the \"0\" exit code. Process output: \"composer/package-versions-deprecated: Generating version class...\ncomposer/package-versions-deprecated: ...done generating version class\nStarting schema dist file generation\nDist file was successfully generated: /app/.magento.env.md\n\"."
      },
      {
        "command": "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run --rm build cloud-build",
        "output": "Finished with the \"1\" exit code. Process output: \"Creating magento_build_run ... \r\n\u001b[1A\u001b[2K\rCreating magento_build_run ...
        .. - Installing abcsolutions/module-dynamics365 (2.2.0): Loading from cache\nPackage container-interop/container-interop is abandoned, \n\nrun <scenario>...\n\n\"."
      }
      
    ]
```

I am unable to know the exact error.

Can you please suggest me what is the issue/reason? here

Comment: Hello, did you manage to fix the issue?

Comment: @MiroslavPetroff, test with docker-compose and docker-cloud

Comment: @Bojjaiah Have you solved the error?

Comment: @Msquare, Yes, solved. Let me know how can I help you?

Comment: @Bojjaiah can you post the solution here?

Comment: @Bojjaiah I am waiting for the solution. Please post your solution here.

Comment: @Msquare, Please create a thread and post your issues. and share the link here. I will look on it.

Comment: @Bojjaiah same above error generate. Please share your solution here.

Comment: @Msquare Posted the reference link. You can follow the documentation to figure out the error. And ping me if any issues. Required either Ubuntu, CentOS, or Mac. I did this in Ubuntu.

Comment: @Bojjaiah  your answer is about installing cloud docker, then what is next step to find actual error? I added module and it is working fine? can you please tell me how to find actual error?

Comment: @Newbie After installing the cloud docker, Please follow the steps (https://github.com/magento/magento-coding-standard) it will show you the error. However, in the normal windows or ubuntu, some of the errors will not show. But in the cloud docker, it will show every issue with the module.

Answer (score 0):

Solved myself by following the [DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/docker/docker-mode-production.html) resources.

Please let me know if any issues while performing the reference documentation operations.

Comment: Hello @Bojjaiah
I have checked with the same steps by docker cloud Building and Deploying but still my module is not passing to submitting on Marketplace. Can you please let me know what do I need to perform addition or missing any?

I have created new thread over magento stackexchange: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/361311/magento-2-marketplace-extension-submission-failed
You can reply over there.

Thanks in Advance!