# Magento 2 marketplace extension submission failed

Tags: magento2, extensions, magento2.4, marketplace, magento2marketplace

I'm facing an issue with the marketplace extension submission. When I try to submit a module on the marketplace and below error report returns from the marketplace.

The report is:

```
{
"tool": "varnish",
  "status": "FAIL",
  "reports": [
    {
      "php_version": "8.1",
      "magento_platform": "M2",
      "magento_edition": "ce",
      "magento_version": "2.4.5-p1",
      "tool": "varnish",
      "vendor": "test",
      "extension": "dev",
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "platform": "m2",
      "magento_cloud_docker": "1.3.3",
      "status": "FAIL"
    }
 ]
}
```

I have checked with docker cloud-build and cloud-deploy on the local machine as below command, and both working fine with my extension.

- docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run --rm build cloud-build
- docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run --rm deploy cloud-deploy

Check the attached screenshot.[image: cloud build and deploy]

Let me know if you have any solution to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: Did you get any errors, while running the website in the docker-compose?

Comment: @Bojjaiah Thanks for the prompt response. There is no error on docker-compose, as the above attached screenshot, it is successfully cloud Building and Deploying.

Comment: Have you tested with Magento Coding Standards https://github.com/magento/magento-coding-standard?

Comment: If already been tested successfully, Can you share your composer file here?

Comment: Yes, I have tested with Magento Coding Standards[phpcs and phpstan] and it tested successfully.
Please find below the composer.json

Answer (score 0):

@Bojjaiah due to too long comment limit, I have pasted here composer.json code. Please find composer.json

```
{
    "name": "test/dev",
    "description": "Dev test module",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "~7.3.0||~7.4.0||~8.0.0||~8.1.0",
        "magento/framework": "103.0.*",
        "test/core": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Test\\Dev\\": ""
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "magento/*": true,
            "laminas/*": true,
            "cweagans/composer-patches": true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `composer.json` looks good. In most cases, the extension failed in the **Varnish**. Did you test the **varnish** test? If No, Please configure and test. Also, they will provide the reason and the stage of compilation failed you can follow the steps that they followed.  Or you can log in to the Magento Slack to get support directly from the Magento Team. https://magentocommeng.slack.com/archives/C7SL5CGDN

Comment: @Bojjaiah Sorry for the late response. I found an exact issue with my module and the issue was related to the console command file. Need to use the Factory class instead of the simple Model class in the Console command file because when marketplace checking module with **docker-Varnish** before the module initialized console command checking and that time class is not being generated so we need to use Factory class and then it works fine. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Great, Congrats.